# Kotlin - Is it possible to get live activity from browser?

Tags: kotlin, browser, history, visited

Is it possible to manage visited website in Kotlin ? Not from browser History, in a live way.
Like to calculate Time you wasted on this website or this website

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to read the time you've been on a website for?

Comment: Yeah exactly so you Can get statistics about the time youv been on a specific website per days, weeks...

Comment: I juste need to target a single website actually